# An example of a Exponential Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Problem:

The lifetime (in hours) $X$ of a certain electronic component is a radon variable with
density function:
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
 \frac{ e^{-\frac{x}{100}} }{100} & \text{ , } x > 0 \\
 0 & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases} $$
Three of these components operate independently in a piece of equipment. The equipment fails if at least
two of the components fail. Find the probability that the equipment operates for at least $200$ hours without
any failure.

Answer:

Let $p$ be the probability we seek. Let $p_f$ be the probability that an electrical component fails in
the first $200$ hours.
\begin{align*}
p_f &= \int_0^{200} \frac{ e^{-\frac{x}{100}} }{100} \,\, dx
 = \frac{ -e^{-\frac{x}{100}} }{100(100)} \Bigg|_0^{200} \\
p_f &= \dfrac{ -e^{-2} }{100(100)} + \dfrac{e^0 }{100(100)} \\
p_f &= \dfrac{ 1 - e^{-2} }{100(100)}  \\
\end{align*}
Let $p_g$ be the probability that a component does not fail in the first $200$ hours.
\begin{align*}
p_g &= 1 - p_f = \dfrac{100(100)}{100(100)} - \dfrac{ 1 - e^{-2} }{100(100)} \\
p_g &= \dfrac{ 9999 +  e^{-2} } { 100(100) } \\
p &= p_g^3 + 3 p_f p_g^2
\end{align*}
Using Scilab, I find that:
$$ p = 1.000000 $$
The book's answer is $0.05$.
Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your integration is not correct.  $$\int \frac{e^{-x/100}}{100} \, dx = -e^{-x/100}+ C,$$ therefore $$\Pr[X \le t] = \int_{x=0}^t \frac{e^{-x/100}}{100} \, dx = 1 - e^{-t/100}.$$  It follows that the probability that a given component fails within $200$ hours is $$p_f = \Pr[X \le 200] = 1 - e^{-2}.$$

The probability that the machine operates for at least $200$ hours without failure is equal to the probability that at most one out of the three components fails; i.e., the number of component failures is a binomial random variable $$Y \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 3, p_f = 1 - e^{-2})$$ and the desired probability is $$\begin{align}
\Pr[Y \le 1] &= \Pr[Y = 0] + \Pr[Y = 1] \\
&= \binom{3}{0} p_f^0 (1-p_f)^3 + \binom{3}{1} p_f^1 (1-p_f)^2 \\
&= (1-p_f)^3 + 3p_f(1-p_f)^2 \\
&= (1-p_f)^2 (1-p_f + 3p_f) \\
&= (1-p_f)^2 (1+2p_f) \\
&= (e^{-2})^2 (1+2(1-e^{-2})) \\
&= e^{-4}(3 - 2e^{-2}) \\
&\approx 0.0499894,
\end{align}$$

as claimed.